# Why no automatic type demotion?

Tags: haskell

I can promote any algebraic value constructor to a type by applying `{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}`. And I expect the type demotion to be same simple and automated, as a promotion. However, given a promoted type `data Test = A | B | C` I can't just `fromSing (sing :: Sing 'A)` Is there any reasons to prevent automatic demotion when a constructors appears to construct a singletons?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are asking.  Are you asking why aren't singletons generated automatically from a `data` definition?

Comment: There's no reason GHC *couldn't* derive instances of `SingI` or `SingE`, but it doesn't. You can use `Data.Singletons.TH` to derive them if you like. I think GHC HQ is much more interested in working out how to get to `DependentHaskell` than trying to add special support for a hack around the *lack* of dependent types.

Comment: Data.Singletons.TH did the job, thanks.